# Significato di "schiodare fuori" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Lessico famigliare* di Natalia Ginzburg ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Oltre al suicidio del Silvio, in casa nostra c’era anche un’altra cosa che veniva sempre velata di un vago mistero, pur riguardando persone di cui si parlava continuamente: ed era il fatto che Turati e la Kuliscioff, non essendo marito e moglie, vivessero insieme. Anche in questa sorta di mistero riconosco soprattutto l’intenzione e i pudori di mio padre, perché mia madre forse, da sola, non ci avrebbe pensato. Sarebbe stato piú semplice che ci mentissero, dicendoci che erano marito e moglie. Invece no; a noi, o almeno a me che ero ancora bambina, veniva nascosto che abitavano insieme; e io, sentendoli sempre nominare in coppia, domandavo perché, e se erano marito e moglie, o fratello e sorella, o cosa. Mi veniva risposto in modo confuso. Non capivo poi da dove l’Andreina, amica d’infanzia di mia madre e figlia della Kuliscioff, **fosse schiodata fuori**, e perché si chiamasse Costa; e non capivo cosa c’entrasse Andrea Costa, che era morto da tempo, e che tuttavia veniva nominato spesso insieme a quelle persone.

Ho cercato alla voce "schiodare" di parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato qual è il senso figurato dell'espressione "schiodare fuori" che appare in questo passaggio. Qualcuno di voi lo saprebbe spiegare?

Comment: Dal contesto sembrerebbe un sinonimo più energico, forse personale (o famigliare), di “spuntata fuori”.

Comment: @DaG:  E "spuntare fuori" significherebbe apparire all'improvviso?

Comment: Sì: Spuntare - mostrarsi improvvisamente sbucando da un qualche posto: *spuntare  fuori da un angolo; da dove sei spuntato?* https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/S/spuntare_1.shtml

Comment: @Hachi: E "spuntare" con questo significato si usa frequentemente seguito da "fuori", no?

Comment: Sì, è comune, l’idea è quella di uscire fuori da un posto nascosto o poco visibile.

Comment: Qui alcuni esempi: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22spuntato%20fuori%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2018,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_it - https://www.google.com/search?q=%22spuntata%20fuori%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2017,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_it

Comment: @Hachi:    Su Google Libri, da "schiodato fuori" invece sono soltanto riuscita a trovare questo esempio: https://books.google.es/books?id=8Xle5KfUcWcC&pg=PA127&lpg=PA127&dq=%22schiodato+fuori%22&source=bl&ots=PNUIykoJGw&sig=ACfU3U25jtBZdppT9EFRrfiNc4XKG6Yz8g&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiG5bGw2pDtAhWOT8AKHSZGDSsQ6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22schiodato%20fuori%22&f=false.

Comment: Sì, non è di uso comune. E il senso è ovviamente metaforico.

Comment: Va bene, DaG e Hachi: grazie! Perlomeno ho imparato qualcosa sul significato e l'uso di "spuntare fuori", espressione che non conoscevo.